# What does this do in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm newbie at C# and couldn't find anything about this:

```
public bool HasUPedidos { get { return upedidos > 0; } }
```

What does this expression does?
Thank you.

Comment: it is a readonly property which returns true if upedidos>0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called a property. That particular one will return true if upedidos is greater than 0, false if not.

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's an Property that returns true if upedidos is greater that 0.

Answer (score 2):

`public` is the visibility (in this case it can be called by things outside the class

`bool` is the return type (boolean can contain either true or false)

`HasUPedidos` is the name of the property

`{ get { return upedidos > 0; } }` this is the get/set methods, in this case only a get. Instead of being bound to a private boolean value this tests to see if we have a value greater than 0 in the variable `upedidos` and returns the result of that test (true or false)

Answer (score 1):

It will return true if `upedidos` is greater than 0.

`upedidos > 0` evaluates to a boolean and reading the value of the `HasUPedidos` property will get that boolean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a public property with name HasUPedios and a return type bool. This will evaluate the expression `upedidos > 0` and return its value.

You can learn about properties in more details at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is a public boolean that returns whether the local variable upedidos ( which I presume is a counter of csome sort ) is greater than 0.

Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a property that only returns, it returns a true/false bool value. True if upedidos is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

That will return `true` if `upedidos` is above zero in value or `false` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

This is property which returns `boolean` value, i.e. `true` if `upedidos` > 0 otherwise `false`

Answer (score 0):

It's a property as others have mentioned, similar to a method like this:

```
public bool getHasUPedidos() {
    if (upepidos > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting downvote, since this is precisely how properties are implemented internally.

Answer (score 0):

Like other admitted this is a property that has only get accessory.
Under the hood. It will convert by the compiler to a method like:

```
bool get_HasUPedidos() { return upedidos > 0;  }
```

if it has a set accessor like:

```
HasUPedidos 
{ 
    get { return upedidos > 0; }
    set { upedidos = value; }
}
```

then it will have another method

```
bool get_HasUPedidos() { return upedidos > 0;  }
bool set_HasUPedidos(bool value) { upedidos = value;  }
```